# Unable to create external directory

Tags: android

I am unable to create a directory in the external storage folder.  I have created a new project, modified the manifest and added the code as seen below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. I updated my post to include that the code provided below does not work.  The only thing I can think is the emulator is the problem.  I am running Nexis API 32 x64.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.us.foobar"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Source:**

```
public void mkdir() throws Exception
{
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String dir = root + "/Foobar";

    File file = new File(dir);
    if (!file.exists())
    {
        if (!file.mkdirs())
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to create application data directory.\r\n\r\nDirectory: " + dir);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ' public MainActivity() throws Exception'm??? Better remove that. Where is onCreate()? Does this even compile? What errors do you have?

Comment: You are not answering my questions. Why aren't you serious? Your code makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I call the same function on onCreate and works fine. Look at my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        test();
    }

    public void test() {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        String dir = root + "/Foobar";

        File file = new File(dir);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e("Error", "Unable to create application data directory.\r\n\r\nDirectory: " + dir);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you serious? Your MainActivity is created at startup by the OS. But the question was where MainActivity() was called. Who would call that? Do you really have a function with that name? Why? Confuse people? Does it compile was my question.

Answer (score 0):

Using API 23 I had to request the permissions prior to writing to the file system as follows:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            );
```